# Create a confirmation alert for delete button in Angular using JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, confirmation

I have a form that has a delete button, I would like to create a confirmation box that pop ups when the delete button is clicked.  The delete button currently works.  I have tried several things in javascript with no luck.  I am using Angular.

Is this best approach for this?

Also, does anyone know of any examples for this, I have not found any that work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").validate();
  $(".radius small success button").ConfirmDialog('Are you sure?');
});
```

Comment: How about some real code instead of psuedo code -- please show us what you have tried, and indicate what is not working.

Comment: @MarkRajcok thats fair, I have added what I have. Any thoughts am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 43):

Seems like an AngularJS directive is a bit over-the-top for a solution to this.  Seems easier just to use straight javascript unless you need some custom functionality to your "confirm()" function.

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
     // TODO:  Do something here if the answer is "Ok".
}
```

Hope this helps, cheers

> **UPDATE**:  Actually, with Angular, it would be better to use $window.confirm as this would allow you to test with Karma/Jasmine.

Comment: this would work fine until the user chooses not to display alerts/confirms in Chrome. In Chrome, when you get a confirm, there is a checkbox "do not show messages like this". And it's gone.

Comment: Sure, but the alerts is on by default.  To prevent that, a directive that handles alert boxes without using confirm() would fix that.

Answer (score 28):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/asafge/7430497)'s another approach at this.
Basically it's a directive that gets the warning string you want to show, and the function to call if the user accepts. Usage example:

```
<button type="button" ng-really-message="Are you sure?"
ng-really-click="delete()">Delete</button>
```

Comment: A basic browser dialog box can be displayed without a directive `if(confirim('Are you sure?')) { Do Something }` does the **exact** same thing which much less overhead.

Comment: Please include all code for your solution in your answer.

Comment: He did include all the necessary code - click on the word 'Here'. And, no, you cannot use confirm with ng-click because you cannot have control flow inside those expressions.

Comment: @GuyArgo it is OK to link to external site, however; all relevant code should be included in the answer in case the site becomes unavailable [See Provide Context for Links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  And the control flow could be placed in the `delete()` method which removes the need for the directive [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/6ctT2/)

Comment: if this needs to be implemented in google extension you can't use inline javascript so directive will be a good solution.

Answer (score 9):

This is how we're handling our 'confirmation dialogs' (using bootstrap)

The Markup

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error notification fade in" data-ng-show="displayLocationDeletePopup">
    <h6>Are you sure you want to delete this location?</h6>
    <div class="form-controls-alert">
        <a href="" class="btn" data-ng-click="showDeleteLocationPopup(false)">No</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="deleteVendorLocation(locationId)">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div><!-- end alert -->
```

Setting model to false on controller load to hide by default with `ng-show`

```
$scope.displayLocationDeletePopup = false;
```

On click on event for show popup, calls a function/passes model in

```
<i class="icon-remove" data-ng-click="showDeleteLocationPopup(true, location)"></i>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.showDeleteLocationPopup = function(options, id) {
    if (options === true) {
        $scope.displayLocationDeletePopup = true;
    } else {
        $scope.displayLocationDeletePopup = false;
    }
    $scope.locationId = id;
};
```

And per the anchors in the html above, can either close the popup or run the function

```
$scope.deleteVendorLocation = function (storeLocation) {
   // Code to run on confirmation            
};
```

Comment: I like this one for bootstrap users.

Answer (score -1):

```
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to Permanently delete this order?");
if (r == true) {
    (OK button click) Write the function here.....
} else {
    (Cancle button click) Write the function here.....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place Delete option on the right hand side of each record and on clicking the delete option the record should get deleted from the details and JSON array.